# Singular solution to a first order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Does the equation
$$y=x(1+y')+y'^2$$
have a singular solution?
When I try to calculate it by solving the following system of equations:
$$F(x,y,y')=0  \text{ and } \frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}=0$$
I get:
$$y=x-\frac{x^2}{4}$$
But my textbook says there are no singular solutions to this differential equation. Then why do I get an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking the Clairaut type ode and deriving it by $x$ we got the system

$$
\cases{
y = x + x p+p^2\\
p = 1 + p + x p' + 2p p'
}
$$

solving the second ode we have

$$
p = W\left(\frac{1}{2} c_1 e^{\frac{x}{2}-1}\right)-\frac{x}{2}+1
$$

where $W(\cdot)$ is the [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function.)

so eliminating $p$ in

$$
\cases{
y = x + x p+p^2\\
p= W\left(\frac{1}{2} c_1 e^{\frac{x}{2}-1}\right)-\frac{x}{2}+1
}
$$

we got

$$
y = \frac{1}{4} \left(4 W\left(\frac{1}{2} c_1 e^{\frac{x}{2}-1}\right){}^2+8
   W\left(\frac{1}{2} c_1 e^{\frac{x}{2}-1}\right)-x^2+4 x+4\right)
$$

now for $c_1=0$ appears

$$
y =1+x -\frac{x^2}{4}
$$

which is a regular solution.

Concerning

$$
\cases{
F(x,y,y')=0 \\
\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}=0
}
$$

we have $y_s = x -\frac{x^2}{4}$ but $y_s$ is not a regular solution. Follows a stream plot showing in blue the phase for $y'=-\frac{1}{2} \left(x\pm\sqrt{x^2-4 x+4 y}\right)$ (two leaves) in blue and $y_s$ in red.

[image]

Comment: Why doesn't this system work? $$\cases{F(x,y,y')=0 \\ \frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}=0}$$ Doesn't it always give you a singular solution?

Comment: Please. See attached continuation.

Comment: Ok but a singular solution is an envelope of the family of general solutions and in this case the red curve is not touching the blue lines at the same angle. Why is that?

Comment: The red curve is an envelope curve.

Comment: But it is not a solution since if we plug it in the differential equation we get $$x-\frac{x^2}{4}=x-\frac{x^2}{4}+1$$

Comment: @Cesareo I don't understand your stream plot, seems you plotted $\{-\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{x^2-4 x+4 y}+x\right),-1\}$ instead of $\{1,-\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{x^2-4 x+4 y}+x\right)\}$ which are the solution curves.

Comment: @gpmath Thanks for the tip. Now corrected.

Answer (score 2):

You should check carefully whether the proposed system $F=0, \partial F/\partial y'=0$ has a solution. In the given problem it does not, whereas a solution will fall out in cases where it does exist. Let's compare your system with a "control" case where the singular solution exists and is well known.

That control case is the equation

$y^2+(y')^2=1$

We have the system

$F=y^2+(y')^2-1=0$  Eq. 1

$\partial F/\partial y'=2y'=0$  Eq. 2

So Eq. 2 implies $y'=0,y=C$ and we plug *both* into Eq. 1. We must then find constant values of $C$ that render Eq. 1 true. Thus

$C^2+0^2-1=0,$

from which the two constants $C=\pm1$ hold and we identify the pair of singular solutions $y=\pm1$.

Now we try this with the given differential equation

$F=y-x-xy'-(y')^2=0$  Eq. 3

$\partial F/\partial y'=-x-2y'=0$ Eq.4

Eq. 4 renders $y'=-x/2,y=-(x^2/4)+C$, so Eq. 3 becomes

$[-(x^2/4)+C]\color{red}{-x}-(x^2/2)+(x^2/4)=0.$

The *leading* terms in $x$ cancel, but the secondary term $-x$ prevents the equation from holding for any integration constant $C$ from Eq. 4. So **we fail to find any singular solution.** This failure shows up in Cesareo's graph as the red boundary curve, $y=x-(x^2)/4$, failing to be tangent to the blue general solution curves.

Comment: But isnt the condition $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}=0$ saying that if at a certain point if we change the slope a little bit our slope field will continue to be smooth because two different lines approach that point from different directions? I'm just confused because I thought it was part of the condition that those two lines are tangent to eachother at that point.

Comment: The condition $\partial F/\partial y=0$ does not guarantee rangency to  singular solution. The general solutions could instead stop and double back on themselves, which us what they do in the graph.